is there a way i can install jenkins on Linux without failing?
Public key for jenkins-2.452.1-1.1.noarch.rpm is not installed
The downloaded packages were saved in cache until the next successful transaction.
You can remove cached packages by executing 'yum clean packages'.
Error: GPG check FAILED
sudo rpm --import http://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io.key

try to ...
sudo wget -O /etc/yum.repos.d/jenkins.repo http://pkg.jenkins-ci.org/redhat-stable/jenkins.repo
sudo rpm --import https://pkg.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/jenkins.io-2023.key
sudo yum install jenkins
(from : https://get.jenkins.io/redhat-stable/)
